# Understanding Hive MR Output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

When I run a Hive statement and the corresponding MR jobs are launched it usually has a line like:

> Stage-Stage-1: Map: 33  Reduce: 131   Cumulative CPU: 8006.47 sec   HDFS Read: 1280804751 HDFS Write: 279261996966 SUCCESS
>
> Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 days 2 hours 13 minutes 26 seconds 470 msec

I had some questions about interpreting that line.

1. What units are the numbers 1280804751, 279261996966 in? Bytes? Blocks? Any way to convert them to human-readable format?
2. What does the "Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent" mean? What does "Cumulative CPU" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The `HDFS Read` and `HDFS Write` values are in bytes.
2. `Cumulative CPU` is the total CPU time of all the tasks of the MapReduce job for the stage. `Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent` is the total CPU time of all of the stages of the query. In your example there is only one stage so both values have the same duration.